# Meteor.Error - custom [reason]

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am throwing a Meteor.Error with a custom [reason] like this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    ...
    if (emailAlreadyExist === true) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "email already registered");
    } else {
      return user
    }
  })
}
```

then trying to show this error message to the user:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
...
    Accounts.createUser({
      email: email,
      password: password
    }, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        // Inform the user that account creation failed
        sAlert.error(error.reason);
      } else {
        // Success.
      }
    });
...
}
```

But this alert does not show my custom `Meteor.Error` [reason], it always gives me "Email already exists".
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because `Accounts.createUser()` is throwing that error, which happens before your `onCreateUser` and thus the callback executes.

Comment: You are right! I've just removed that validation from the `isServer` and I still can get error if an email is already registered. It means that `Accounts.createUser()` has it's own validation built in. Actually, I just checked with the docs and there is said " If there are existing users with a username or email only differing in case, createUser will fail."